# How to handle UITextField value change without delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextviewdelegate

There is a method in UITextFieldDelegate

```
textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)
```

Which allows me to do it. But I want custom text field handle this automatically to update its state without delegate and I don't want to use delegate internally as it can be overridden. How should I do this?

For example there is a method - becomeFirstResponder which I override to show/hide validation error when text field resigns from being first responder, but there seems to be nothing for handling text property changes, or was I inattentive?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`.

Or you could subclass so you can be your own delegate and also forward delegate calls to another delegate which is added (so your internal delegate is a proxy for the real delegate, handling the call and then forwarding it).